# Why did the goblet spit Harry's name out in the first place?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-goblet-of-fire

In **Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire**, only three people (one from each school) can be selected for the tri-wizard tournament.

All champions  can only be over the age of 17 to join.

So Harry, being only 14 and in his *fourth year* got chosen to participate... and it just so happens to be that he is the *fourth* contestant, which is against the rules.

*How did Harry get chosen and why?*

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by this question. It's clearly a pretty up-front plot point, set out as a mystery towards the start and then made plain towards the end.

Comment: Upvoted because it's been a while since I read the book, so I'd forgotten the answer.  (And because this question attracted AJ's very nice answer.)

Comment: SciFi related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22621/25379

Comment: Why do you guys go "oh good question, let's upvote', and then you suddenly start down-voting  and claim that some other site that appears to be the same question pops up in the comments? Why couldn't you tell me this BEFORE? As I would have deleted the question to make things easier?

Comment: Well, we vote based on the question my friend. We don't see comments.  You will notice that there are no upvotes on the link from the other site. It means that people didn't vote after looking at the comments but voted looking at the question. We DON"T want you to delete the question and we want you to post questions because they attract good answers and help the site.  What happens on sister site has nothing to do with this site. :)

Comment: ... Thought it was the whole plot point! If you want to avoid spoilers, you should go finish reading the book / watching the movie.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The Goblet can only spit the fourth candidate if it is bewitched. It takes a strong charm to do this.

> **MAD-EYE:** The hell he is. The goblet of fire is an exceptionally powerful magical object, only an exceptionally powerful conjurer could have hoodwinked it. Magic way beyond the talents of a fourth year.

It was later revealed that Barty Crouch Jr., who was disguised as Mad-Eye, did it and he knew the way to do so.

Later, near the end of the movie,

> **Harry Potter:** It was you from the beginning. You put my name in the Goblet of Fire.

From the novel in the 17th chapter,

> “Because they hoodwinked a very powerful magical object!” **said Moody.** “It would have needed an exceptionally strong Confundus Charm  to bamboozle  that goblet into forgetting that only three schools compete in the 
>   tournament… I’m guessing they submitted Potter’s name under a fourth  school, to make sure he was the only one in his category…”

So, it's clear he already knew how to bewitch the Goblet. And he put Harry's name in under a fourth school.

In 35th chapter, Moody says,

> “**Who put your name in the Goblet of Fire, under the name of a different  school?  I  did.**  Who  frightened  off  every  person  I  thought might  try  to  hurt  you  or  prevent  you  from  winning  the  tournament?  I  did. Who  nudged  Hagrid  into  showing  you  the  dragons?  I  did. Who helped you see the only way you could beat the dragon? I did.”

The age criterion was set at 17, so Dumbledore set the charm around the goblet since, as it seems, the goblet doesn't care about the age. Harry wasn't seventeen, but Mad-Eye was older than 17, so he easily crossed the boundary.

From 12th chapter,

> “Eager  though  I  know  all  of  you  will  be  to  bring  the  Triwizard Cup  to  Hogwarts,”  he  said,  “the  heads  of  the  participating  schools,
>   along with the Ministry of Magic, have agreed to impose an age restriction on contenders this year. **Only students who are of age — that is to say, seventeen years or older — will be allowed to put forward their names for consideration. This**” — Dumbledore raised his voice slightly, for several people had made noises of outrage at these words, and the Weasley twins were suddenly looking furious — “**is a  measure  we  feel  is  necessary**,  given  that  the  tournament  tasks  will  still be difficult and dangerous, whatever precautions we take, and it is highly unlikely that students be
>   low sixth and seventh year will be able to cope with them. **I will personally be ensuring that no under-age student hoodwinks our impartial judge into making them Hogwarts champion.**” His light blue eyes twinkled as they lickered over Fred’s and George’s mutinous faces. “I therefore beg you not to waste 
>   your time submitting yourself if you are under seventeen.

So, in conclusion, Barty Crouch Jr. bewitched the goblet so it can forget that there are only three schools participating. Later, he put Harry's name in it and since he was the only candidate from that false school, the goblet spat his name out.

Comment: Note that, when the Goblet spat out a sheet with Harry's name, it lacked a school name on it.

Comment: So the goblet considered SCHOOL = NULL to be a distinct value from the other 3.

Comment: Chould be school = " "

Comment: `SCHOOL = '); DROP TABLE Students;--`?

Comment: I see programmers from StackOverflow started to overflow to Movies SE site. I wonder how many people have we managed to confuse by now with those comments.

Comment: Hot Network Questions are gonna draw in the riff raff...

Comment: @DavidFoerster [Great minds joke alike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129616/what-school-name-was-used-to-enter-harry-into-the-goblet-of-fire#comment327048_129616)

Comment: @DavidFoerster that's missing the trailing `--` though. Gotta comment out the code that was intended to come next.